# Open subset of a scheme is also a scheme

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

In order to prove that any open subset $(U, \mathcal{O}_X|_U)$ of a scheme $(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ is a scheme, we have to show the following two materials.

1)  $(U, \mathcal{O}_X|_U)$ is a locally ringed space, namely, each stalk of $\mathcal{O}_X|_U $ is a local ring.

In fact, any germ $<U \cap G, s>$  of $(U, \mathcal{O}_X|_U)$ at the point $p \in U$    is also a germ of  $(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$, there is map between stalk $(\mathcal{O}_X|_{U})_{p } \to \mathcal{O}_{X,p} $. The inverse mapping of this is obvious. Thus, $(\mathcal{O}_X|_{U})_{p } \cong (\mathcal{O}_X)_{p }$ and by the assumption, $(\mathcal{O}_X)_{p }$ is a local ring and thus $(\mathcal{O}_X|_{U})_{p } $ is also  a local ring.

2)Any point of $U$, there is an open neighborhood of $U$ such that it is a spectrum of some ring.

I cannot prove this.

The following is my attempt.
Because any point of $U$ is also a point of $X$ and $X$ is a scheme, there is an open neighborhood $G$ of $X$ (not $U$) such that $G \cong $ Spec $R(G)$ for some ring $R(G)$. Because any open set of $U$  can be written by $U \cap G$, we can obtain an open subset of Spec $R(G)$ which is homeomorphic to  $U\cap G$. However I cannot find a ring $R(G \cap U)$ such that  $U\cap G \cong$  Spec $R(G \cap U)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have shown reduces the problem to the case when $X$ itself is affine.

So, let $X=\mathrm{Spec}\,A$ be an affine scheme. Then the distinguished opens $D(a)$ for $a\in A$ form a base for the Zariski topology (and this base is closed under finite intersections). Moreover, we have $D(a)=\mathrm{Spec}\,A_a$, the affine scheme corresponding to the localisation $A_a$.

It follows that if $U\subseteq X$ is any open, then we can write $U$ as a union of distinguished opens. This completes the proof of (2).

Comment: $U=\cup_f D(f)$ and take open set $G$ of $U$, then what is a ring such that $G $ is homemorphic  to the set of prime ideals of the ring? The desired ring is $\Sigma _{f \notin G} A_f$?

Comment: $D(a)=\{\mathfrak p\lhd A\mid a\not\in\mathfrak p\}$, so if $U=\bigcup_{a\in S}D(a)$, then $U=\{\mathfrak p\lhd A\mid a\not\in\mathfrak p\textrm{ for some }a\in S\}$. Of course, a general open subset of an affine scheme will not itself be affine (they are called quasi-affine schemes).

Comment: Any open set of Spec $A$ can be written union of $D(f)=$ Spec $A_f$. There are simple algebraic relation such that $D(f)\cap D(g) =D(fg)=$  Spec $A_{(fg)}$ and  $D(f)\cup D(g) =D( (f)+(g)  )=$  Spec $A_{(f)+(g)}$ where the second relation is available for the infinite unions. These relation reveal the rings and thus each open subset of scheme is  a spectrum.

Comment: If you take the plane minus the origin, then this is open in $\mathbb A_2$ but is not affine, so is not spec of any ring.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer:** The pair $(U, (\mathcal{O}_X)_U)$ is a locally ringed space since the restriction $(\mathcal{O}_X)_U$ of $\mathcal{O}_X$ to the open set $U$ is sheaf of rings with the same stalks as $\mathcal{O}_X$ and these are local rings:

$$((\mathcal{O}_X)_U)_x \cong \mathcal{O}_{X,x}.$$

Given any point $x\in U$ there is an open affine scheme $x\in V:=Spec(A)\subseteq X$ containing $x$. Since $x\in V \cap U$ and since $V\cap U \subseteq V$ is an open set, there is a basic open set $x\in D(f):=Spec(A_f)$ containing $x$. It follows $D(f) \subseteq U$ is open in $U$ and hence $(U, (\mathcal{O}_X)_U)$ has an open cover consisting of affine schemes.